# Azure Recovery Vault backup configuration missing the Cross Region Restore option?

Tags: azure, disaster-recovery, backup-strategies, azure-site-recovery

My recovery vault is in the West US 2 region, and I cannot see the option to enable a Cross region restore as seen in the Azure documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-create-rs-vault#set-cross-region-restore).

Screenshot from documentation shows this option:
[image]

My Azure UI:
[image]

Question: Why is this feature not available to be enabled for me? The documentation doesn't have any details about the eligibility for support.

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered this feature?

Before you begin, you must register it through PowerShell. Also keep in mind it is a preview feature ([have a look at this page](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/blog/cross-region-restore-crr-for-azure-virtual-machines-using-azure-backup/)).

```
Register-AzProviderFeature -FeatureName CrossRegionRestore -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.RecoveryServices

FeatureName        ProviderName               RegistrationState
-----------        ------------               -----------------
CrossRegionRestore Microsoft.RecoveryServices Registering
```

It might take up to 48 hours, you can check status.

```
Get-AzProviderFeature -FeatureName CrossRegionRestore -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.RecoveryServices

FeatureName        ProviderName               RegistrationState
-----------        ------------               -----------------
CrossRegionRestore Microsoft.RecoveryServices Registered
```